# Swift Tableview search result cell click to checkmark not showing

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, searchbar

In my case, I am loading `JSON` data with help of `codable` into UITableView. Here, Tableview multiple cell `checkmark` option I am implemented. Now, I have two array `filteredData` and `membersData`. Without search if I click checkmark working but after search result if I click checkmark not showing. Also, after selection need to save the value from filterdata result to main datasource. How to solve this?

**My Tableview Delegates**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return searching ? filteredData.count : membersData.count
    }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell:TeamlistCustomCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellReuseIdentifier) as! TeamlistCustomCell
        let textForRow = searching ? filteredData[indexPath.row] : membersData[indexPath.row]
        cell.name.text = textForRow.firstname
        return cell
    }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        self.tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        membersData[indexPath.row].isSelected.toggle()
        tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)
        let selectedAreas = membersData.filter{$0.isSelected}
}
```

**SearchBar TextDidChange**

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        if !searchText.isEmpty {
            filteredData = membersData.filter({ ($0.firstname?.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(searchText))! })
            searching = true
        } else {
            filteredData.removeAll()
            searching = false
        }
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

**Storing Selected Values CheckMark**

```
func saveSelection() {
        let selectedAreaNames = membersData.filter{$0.isSelected}.map{$0.userid}
        UserDefaults.standard.set(selectedAreaNames, forKey: "selectedNames")

        let selectedData = membersData.filter{$0.isSelected}
        UserDefaults.standard.set(try? PropertyListEncoder().encode(selectedData), forKey:"session data")

        delegate?.pass(data: selectedData) //call the func in the previous vc
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

complete code

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        self.tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        if  searching == false {
            membersData[indexPath.row].isSelected.toggle()
        } else {
            filteredData[indexPath.row].isSelected.toggle()
        }
        tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202026/discussion-on-answer-by-sgdev-swift-tableview-search-result-cell-click-to-checkm).